# Mobs spawning in different biomes in terraria

Tags: terraria-mobile

I have started having mobs spawn in different biomes then they are supposed to be.Harpies are also spawning close to the ground and Crimson mobs are spawning in the jungle.[image]

Comment: What size world were you on? In Small worlds, the ground sometimes can get high enough that the surface could get close to or inside the high-altitude regions.

Comment: There is crimson in terraria mobile?  I have made 13 worlds till today deleting previous one in hope of getting a crimson world.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks from that screenshot - with the wooden block staircase - a lot like you were just trying to climb into the upper altitudes.  If that's the case, the harpies would have spawned while you were up there, and simply followed you down from their usual haunts.

Something similar probably happened with the Crimson too, unless you have other info.  Biomes aren't walled gardens, and not every creature is easily left behind.

Comment: The wooden staircase is there to about a couple blocks higher than the screen and the Crimson biome is no where near the jungle.